# The -> symbol in perl, and perl style

Tags: perl, oop, cgi

I was reading a book about perl CGI for a project.
I found several examples online that was used

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
```

another that did

```
print header;
```

and finally

```
print $q->header;
```

I am a bit confused now, how to tackle this perl cgi page.
A lot of guides use the `->` symbol which I believe is used in Object Oriented Perl. Is my assumption correct that , the `->` symbols are used for that?

Do all of these methods accomplish the same goal correctly?

Many of the books I have seen in my library are relatively old(1990's), and do not mention object oriented perl.  Is that the style that perl developers now use?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#PROGRAMMING-STYLE for the specifics of the two styles as they relate to `CGI.pm`. I'll leave it to someone else to answer your more general question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$q->cgi` is indeed a method call. CGI subs can be called as methods or as functions. It checks the arguments and uses a local object if one wasn't used in the call.